# I would like to create custom PreviewView for barcode with cameraX

Tags: java, android, android-layout, kotlin, android-camera

I would like to create custom PreviewView for barcode with CameraX, I don't find enough resources for custom UI with CameraX.

***Which custom classes should I implement (to make Custom UI) and how should I register the UI to CameraX preview?***

// create preview usecase

```
 val previewUseCase = Preview.Builder()
        .setTargetAspectRatio(screenAspectRatio)
        .setTargetRotation(previewView!!.display.rotation)
        .build()
```

//attach surfaceprovicer

```
 previewUseCase!!.setSurfaceProvider(previewView!!.createSurfaceProvider())
```

// bind

```
cameraProvider!!.bindToLifecycle(/* lifecycleOwner= */this, cameraSelector!!, previewUseCase)
```

[image: I would like to create UI like that]

Comment: How did you workout with this?